# issue with using Style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

Can I write following code using STYLE in xaml?

```
cmbEnquiry.IsEnabled = (txtQuotationNo.IsEnabled && txtQuotationNo.IsReadOnly == false);
```

Comment: You'd have to use multi-variable databinding within your style

Comment: any code sample plz? or may be u can use above controls in the xaml-code

Comment: dont be lazy, just google style multibinding trigger

Comment: blindmeis, it's ok if u don't comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work as is as I'm not in front of an IDE and am trying to code from memory, but if nothing else, it'll serve as an example for MultiBinding.

In your resources:

```
<local:AndNotConverter x:Key="AndNotConverter" />
<Style ...>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AndNotConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="txtQuotationNo" Path="IsEnabled" />
                <Binding ElementName="txtQuotationNo" Path="IsReadOnly" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style
```

In your code-behind:

```
public class AndNotConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return (bool)values[0] && !((bool)values[1]);
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Just verified the code, and it works as expected.